# Symfony2: form is not created

Tags: php, forms, symfony

There is a   form to create Chain entity.

```
class ChainType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
    * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
    * @param array $options
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Company name'))
            ->add('logoImageURL', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Company logo'));
    }

    /**
    * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
    */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CoreBundle\Entity\Chain'
        ));
    }
}
```

Here is a newAction to create form and save entity

```
/**
* Creates a new Chain entity.
*
* @Route("/new", name="chain_new")
*/
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $chain = new Chain();
    $form = $this->createForm(ChainType::class, $chain);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($chain);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('chain_show');
    }

    return $this->render(
        'AdminBundle:ChainPanel:new.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

Here is a button to create form

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    <a href="{{ path('chain_new') }}">
        Add Chain
    </a>
</button>
```

**Problem**

When I click on 'Add chain' button the form is not created and I m just redirected to 'chain_show' route. What is wrong with my code?

**UPDATE - MY SOLUTION**

In controller I put newAction before showAction. This fixed problem. However I couldn't find explanation

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but if you're trying to create a page with ChainType form you should also create a template for that page, like this:

```
.....

{% block YOUR_BLOCK %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}

......
```

and, also, you don't have to wrap `a` tag with `button` tag, just give `class="btn btn-primary"` to that `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're using the variable which holds the new Chain object. Please see my example below and this should fix your problem...

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $chain = new Chain();
    $form = $this->createForm(ChainType::class, $chain);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $chain = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($chain);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('chain_show');
    }

    return $this->render(
        'AdminBundle:ChainPanel:new.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

You're also creating the submit button incorrectly. To test it's all working properly, just use (in your .twig.html file):

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting though, I guess the HTML is wrong for a link. You shouldn't have `button` wrapped to an anchor tag. Some browsers doesn't support it. instead use as below :

```
<a href="{{ path('chain_new') }}" class="btn btn-primary">
    Add Chain
</a>
```

If this doesn't solve your issue, Do you see a new entity being created when you click on the link?

Answer (score 0):

In controller I put newAction before showAction. This fixed problem. However I couldn't find explanation